# When should I use setQueryPayment() for query a smart contract?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I have a question regarding the call of a smart contract function, I saw that I can specify a setQueryPayment() when I'm using ContractCallQuery().

I would like to know when I need to use the setQueryPayment() when I'm doing a ContractCallQuery() on my smart contract ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Hedera Network, the states of smart contracts are stored in consensus nodes which have limited resource so you have to pay some fee to read data.

To answer your question, `setQueryPayment` allows you to specify the amount of Hbar you want to pay for your request. In most case, you don't need to set it as the SDK will try to calculate the transaction fee automatically. However, there are some unusual cases where the estimated fee is not accurate so you have to override it by calling `setQueryPayment`.

Therefore, you don't need to set it most of the time but if you are facing some errors related to gas/fee, setting query payment might solve your problem.